# get rid of the titlepage in Quarto (PDF Output)

Tags: latex, markdown, quarto

I want to get rid of the title page in Quarto but did not get it. I've found some option that have no effect in my document https://github.com/periodicpoint/robusta/blob/master/settings/00_00_settings.yaml

```
custom_title_page: false
format:
  pdf:
    classoption:
      - 'titlepage=false'
```

Maybe i'm just irritated and it's trivial

```
---
title: "test"
format: pdf
---

text
```

gives a title

```
---
format: pdf
---

text
```

gives no title. But maybe there is also a switch in yaml to omit the title page even if the title is set?

Comment: Can you add a fully reproducible example? Not just the yaml section?

Comment: @shafee please excuse the delay, I've tried to make it more concrete, but since I now know that it is enough to omit the title tag, it is okay. It is usually specified in the beginner examples, so I did not come up with the trivial solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily using a [Pandoc Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html), which will remove the document title even if the title is set and this will work not just for `pdf` output, but also `html` and `docx`.

```
---
title: "Title"
format: pdf
filters: [remove_title.lua]
---

text
```

**remove_title.lua**

```
function Meta(m)
  m.title = nil
  return m
end
```